# How to make android button open a page number in java

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

I am new to java, and I am still learning, can anyone help in this respect in their spare time?I am trying to do a 10 page poem, just to start with.

I have created buttons that look like a number pad, I am trying to make this number work when it has been pressed/clicked. I am able to make the numbers show when pressed. However, where I am having problems is how to make this number open another layout I have created with a number.

Say I have created a layout and I want it to be page 7, how do I set it such that when number 7 is pressed (it shows the first line / title of the poem) and when the "Go" button is clicked, it opens the layout with poem number 7.

Thank you

**EDIT**

I followed what you told me and now I have one layout and one fragment class.

```
`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/text_fragment_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvpoem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

`

and the fragment java class is like:
public class PoemMapFrag extends Fragment

```
`{  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragpoemsmap, container, false);
    TextView fragpageone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvpoems);
    fragpageone.setText("Testing");
    return view;

}

public View onCreateView1(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragpoemsmap, container, false);
    TextView fragpagetwo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvpoems);
    fragpagetwo.setText("Yawning");
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}`
```

Comment: Is this new layout associated with a new activity?

Comment: please share the layout associated with it.

Comment: @doydoy what would be the best step to use in this?

Comment: @2dee's answer seems to cover this. FYI I would use their suggestion if I were implementing this system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to handle button clicks is to assign it an OnClickListener, like so :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //start a new activity or replace the Fragment in view
    }
};
```

For your particular case, you could use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to show each page, using a [FragmentTransaction to replace the Fragment in view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29). If you use an Activity, you would have 10 OnCLickListeners (one for each page), so I wouldn't advise it.

Alternatively, you could just use a swipe gesture to switch Fragment, thus getting rid of your button. [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) is designed for this, and you could use [Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) library to give a visual feedback of which page is in view.

If you need me to clarify something, don't hesitate to ask ;-)

**EDIT :** As per your request, here's how I would do it using Fragments:

Create a Fragment for each page. You can re-use the same layout each time, containing only a TextView with the text for your page, with width and height set as match_parent. In the fragment's onCreateView, you get a reference to the textview like so :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page_layout, container, false);

    // Get references to layout elements
    pageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.article_paragraph_title);
    return view;
}
```

and in the onActivityCreated :

```
pageTextView.setText(yourTextForThisPage);
```

In your activity you can either set a button to switch page, or use a ViewPager. The main idea is that the Activity will take care of switching Fragment, thus changing the text in view, since every time you change Fragment, a new Fragment should be created an replace the preceding one. You can use the links I provide above to get you started, or follow [THIS TUTORIAL](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/view-pager-example-in-android-development/), which seems to achieve more or less what I was trying to explain. I hope this clarifies a bit...

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you how to write one Fragment code, and just re-use the same class and its layout.

Comment: No problemo ;) I would suggest you read about Fragments carefully, it is a very important component of the Android framework. Happy coding !

Comment: Was on it all through the night, and I still didnt get anywhere... How would the layout be like?
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pg1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/pg2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>

Like that?

Comment: no, I would define it as : <LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/text_fragment_pager" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/></LinearLayout>, define a list of texts that your fragments will use, and use a private class FragmentPagerAdapter in your activity to switch fragment. You will only need one Fragment class that way, which will take its text through a bundle you supply in the activity.

Comment: Try to follow the tutorial I provided at the end of my answer first, it will give you a better idea of how this is done ;-)

Comment: This is really more complicated than I thought it would.
Ok, after lots of reading, I'd appreciate if you go slowly with me please. Since the poem app to be made is a 10page, I have to create 10 fragments layout for each page yeah?
Do I have to create 10 separate java class for each of these 10 layouts? because that will just make it look like the onClickmethod.
Or is it that I create this 10 separate fragments layout, containing the textView as you said, and then link all this 10 fragments layout in one fragmentcontainer.java class and then link them separately?

Comment: If so, how do I link the Textviews when only one onCreateView can be created.

This is where I am confused. Most tutorials on fragments use the ListView and Display example which makes it sort of hard for me. and when I checked to add fragments dynamically, in the setContentView, there is another layout.xml that totally confuses me again.

Comment: One fragment class and one layout only. Your activity contains a List of texts, one text for each fragment. When you build your fragment from your activity, you provide the proper text as a Bundle, according to the page number and you take care of changing fragment (the text in the bundle depends on the position provided as int the the getitem method of the FragmentPagerAdapter) . In your fragment, your read the string inside the bundle and assign it to the textview. Follow the tutorial ;)

Comment: Thank you for being there. I'm beginning to understand how fragment works, so now I have just one layout containing a textview, and one java class, as you will notice above in my Q. I used two onCreateView (onCreateView&onCreateView1) I am not sure if I got it correctly, but following your instruction, I thought that would be how to go about it. the first onCreateView uses the TextView id but displays the first Text: Testing while the second onCreateView displays the second Text: Yawning.

I want to know if I am doing this right, now I have 2 look up our to make it display in an activity

Comment: When I insert the code in the onActivityCreated, it gives an error, on looking at other tutorials, I had to leave the onActivityCreated blank, so if you can clarify that, I will be greatful! Thanks again for not ignoring! @2Dee

Comment: The code you provide is completely wrong :-) You need to have the viewpager in the activity's layout and only one oncreateview method. Did you follow the tutorial I provided ??

Comment: In the tutorial you gave they had a java class for each layout that is the (details layout/details java) and the (image layout/image java). But you told me I would need just one java class. Plus , I do not know what the (Log) does. Guess I'm making this hard for you.. (I feel dumb).

Comment: If you dont mind, could you be able to set this up for me for a three page poem? I can download the source code, and then I'm sure I will understand. Thanks

Comment: Ok, had some time so I made you an example, you can find the code here : https://github.com/toodee/PagerPoemExample
May I ask you to mark the answer as accepted so this does not appear in active questions ? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, could you help me with this Q too: is this code correct: 
String check = display.getText().toString(); 
if (check.contentEquals("1")) { 
tvtitle.setText("Twinkle Twinkle Little Star"); } 
else { tvtitle.setText(""); }

Is it possible to pass data between two TextViews in the same activity using the above code? I tried it, it didnt work, maybe I did something wrong, if you could please help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691070/fragment-arraylist-linking

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```java
Button go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BUTTON_ID);
go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Poem_7.class)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
});
```

Comment: hello and thank you, If I am to use this, do I have to create a poem_7 class?